# How to permanently save power options in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, power-options

How can I set the hard disk to never turn off permanently?And the sleep to never, together with the hibernate.
Because the options resets to their default values when I turn off, log off or restart my computer.
I am using granola on my laptop and it is set to lowest speed. When I restart it turns to full power again. Does it have something to do with the power options resetting to their default values?

Answer (score 2):

To change/set power options in Windows 7:

Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > change when the computer sleeps > click on Advanced Settings

A Power Options dialog box will pop up with all the options within it.

Select option required > High Performance, Hibernate, Sleep, Display, USB, etc.

Highlight to change time period up/down or to never if you wish. Click on Apply > click OK.

As for it resetting to default values, your machine and Windows may need full power to start. Granola after starting with Windows should control the power settings, changing up/down as needed.

How does it work when other settings are used? You may need to reinstall. It looks like a good program.